# Additive Function Overloading?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Let's say I have a base class and a derived class:

```
struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Do one thing." << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B: public A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Do another thing." << std::endl;
    }
};

B myB;
myB.foo();
```

Normally this would print `Do another thing.`, but what if I wanted `foo()` to also run the base `foo()` and print:

```
Do one thing.
Do another thing.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `A::foo()` in `B::foo()`, that way the base class's function will execute first, then the rest of the derived class function executes after that.

```
struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Do one thing." << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void foo()
    {
        A::foo();
        std::cout << "Do another thing." << std::endl;
    }
};
```